# Block URLs and encrypt hosts file

Tags: security, browser, es-file-explorer, hosts, url

I am looking to block a few URLs from an android device... however, I would like to take an extra level of security and password protect the hosts file.

I think I can do that with ES File Explorer by the looks of it?
https://www.howtogeek.com/221582/19-things-you-didnt-know-androids-es-file-explorer-can-do/amp/

I'm wondering, if I encrypt the hosts file but then uninstall ES File Explorer, will the hosts file stay encrypted?

Or if not, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Well, if the hosts file is encrypted, what use will it be? It cannot be read then and thus not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encrypt the hosts file, the system won't be able to read the file, so it won't work any more. But there's no need: since you need root access to edit the hosts file anyway, any app that you don't grant root access won't be able to edit the file.